# Apache (Solaris 10): 2 symlinks to the same file, one works the other doesn't

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm seeing a strange issue with Apache

I have a system that pulls a configuration file from a web server. I want to use a symlink with the name 'ocds-dpsarch01a.rules'. This doesn't work. However, if I change one character in that name and link it to the same file, it works - See below

I can't think of any reason why one symlink would work when another doesn't? I would have thought either the Apache configuration is right and all symlinks work, or it isn't and no syslinks work(?)

Any thoughts welcome

```
# ls -l /REMOVED/apache2/htdocs/rules/syslog/*cds-dpsarch01a.rules
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          62 May 13 13:55 ocds-dpsarch01a.rules -> /REMOVED/apache2/htdocs/templates/syslog/DCM_SST_DPST_01.rules
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          62 May 13 13:52 xcds-dpsarch01a.rules -> /REMOVED/apache2/htdocs/templates/syslog/DCM_SST_DPST_01.rules
```

1) Application starting and successfully reading configuration from the web server

```
13/05/2010 13:56:37: Information: Connecting ...
13/05/2010 13:56:37: Debug: Reading REMOVED:// REMOVED /rules/syslog/xcds-dpsarch01a.rules
13/05/2010 13:56:37: Debug: HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 May 2010 13:56:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 12:28:26 GMT
ETag: "5073-a744-ee92ae80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 42820
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Expires: Thu, 13 May 2010 13:56:39 GMT
NL7C-Filtered:
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close

13/05/2010 13:56:37: Debug: Plain text rules file detected.
```

2) Application starting and failing to read configuration from the web server

```
13/05/2010 13:56:55: Information: Connecting ...
13/05/2010 13:56:55: Debug: Reading REMOVED :// REMOVED /rules/syslog/ocds-dpsarch01a.rules
13/05/2010 13:56:55: Debug: HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 12 May 2010 15:25:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Language: en
Expires: Wed, 12 May 2010 15:25:11 GMT


13/05/2010 13:56:55: Error: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 12 May 2010 15:25:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Language: en
Expires: Wed, 12 May 2010 15:25:11 GMT


13/05/2010 13:56:55: Error: HTTP GET failed
13/05/2010 13:56:55: Error: Failed to open Rules file: REMOVED :// REMOVED /rules/syslog/ocds-dpsarch01a.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the requesting application is treating the two names differently?  Check out the request headers on the 2 HTTP requests and make sure they're the same.

You should also look at the .htaccess file(s) governing that directory, if any, as well as the httpd.conf, to see if there are any rules protecting files with a particular name.  This reference may help: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#file-and-web

Comment: Thanks for your reply

After some in-depth investigation with Sun (Oracle), we've found that the root of the issue was the NCA (Network Cache and Accelerator) feature causing stale responses from Apache. I've disabled that feature in /etc/nca/ncakmod.conf (which was enabled as part of our standard Web Server Build) and rebooted the Server and this has resolved the issue